# SSRS. how can I group data into categories?

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I think this is trivial, but I'm still a SSRS newbie...

Anyway, from my data set I'm able to Group and visualize data like this:

```
Place |Score 
=================
place1|score1
place2|score2
etc.  |etc.
```

Every score value is a sum aggregation of values. Now, I'd like to display all these values like this:

```
Evalutation | # of places<br>
===============================<br>
Bad         | # of places with less than 40% "good" scores <br>
Good        | # of places with more than 40%, less than 70% "good" scores <br>
Excellent   | # of places with more than 70% "good" scores <br>
```

A good score is defined by two calculated attributes being not empty. I'm really stuck here. Any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some sample base data (not what your dataset is currently producing) and what your expected output would be based on that sample data.

Comment: Ok! My table is like this:

happening | place | boolean attribute 1 | booleann attribute 2 | isGood

isGood is set to true if the booleans are both true.

I'd like to classify then each place by (good happenings/total number of happenings). If said percentage is <40% then place = insufficient, if percentage is >40% and <=70% place = good, if percentage >70% place = excellent. 

I don't knwo how to do the next step - how to count the number of insufficient, good and excellent places.

Comment: You need to edit your question and format the the table layout. It's impossible to make sense of in a comment

Comment: Upvoted solely because you called yourself Crappotronic.